# Allowing permission using S3FS bucket directory for other users

Tags: s3fs

I'm having problem using S3FS. I'm using

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ /usr/bin/s3fs --version
Amazon Simple Storage Service File System 1.71
```

And I have the password file installed in the `/usr/share/myapp/s3fs-password` with `600` permission.

I have succeeded mounting the S3 bucket.

```
sudo /usr/bin/s3fs -o allow_other -opasswd_file=/usr/share/myapp/s3fs-password -ouse_cache=/tmp mybucket.example.com /bucket
```

And I have `user_allow_other` enabled in the `/etc/fuse.conf`

When I tried creating a file in the bucket as `root` it worked.

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ sudo su
root@ip-x-x-x-x:/home/ubuntu# cd /bucket
root@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket# echo 'Hello World!' > test-`date +%s`.txt
root@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket# ls
test-1373359118.txt
```

I checked the bucket `mybucket.example.com`'s content and the file was successfully created.

But I was having difficulties writing into the directory `/bucket` as different user.

```
root@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket# exit
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ cd /bucket
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ echo 'Hello World!' > test-`date +%s`.txt
-bash: test-1373359543.txt: Permission denied
```

I desperately tried chmod-ing to `777` the `test-1373359118.txt`. And I can write into the file

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ sudo chmod 777 test-1373359118.txt
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ echo 'Test' > test-1373359118.txt
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ cat test-1373359118.txt
Test
```

Funnily, I could create a directory inside the bucket, set the chmod to `777`, and write a file there.

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ sudo mkdir -m 1777 test
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ ls
test  test-1373359118.txt
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket$ cd test
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket/test$ echo 'Hello World!' > test-`date +%s`.txt
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket/test$ ls
test-1373360059.txt
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/bucket/test$ cat test-1373360059.txt
Hello World
```

But then I tried

```
ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:~$ sudo chmod 777 /mybucket
chmod: changing permissions of '/mybucket': Input/output error
```

It didn't work.

Initially I was thinking to use this `/bucket` directory to store large and rarely accessed files from my LAMP stacks located several EC2 machines. (I think it's suitable enough to use this without making a special handling library using AWS PHP SDK, but that's not the point.)

Because of that reason, I can settle using a directory inside the `/mybucket` to store the files. But I'm just curious if there is a way to allow entire `/mybucket` to other users?

Comment: it seems the answer is umask. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62693432/1421036

Answer (score 34):

Permission was an issue with older versions of S3FS. Upgrade to latest version to get it working.

As already stated in the question itself and other answers, While mounting you will have to pass the following parameters: `-o allow_other`

Example:

```
s3fs mybucket:/ mymountlocation/ -o allow_other
```

Also, before doing this ensure the following is enabled in `/etc/fuse.conf`:

```
user_allow_other
```

It is disabled by default ;)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work recursively, meaning I cannot access the subdirectories in the S3 bucket even though the `allow_other` option is set (as well as `user_allow_other`)

Comment: @mj3c it seems the answer is umask. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62693432/1421036

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
s3fs ec2downloads:/ /mnt/s3 -o use_rrs -o allow_other -o use_cache=/tmp
```

It must have been fixed in a recent version, I'm using the latest clone (1.78) from the [github project](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/releases).

Comment: I'm using version 1.90 and it still does not work recursively as @mj3c commented

Answer (score 4):

This is the only thing that worked for me:

You can pass the `uid` option to make sure it does:

```
    -o umask=0007,uid=1001,gid=1001 # replace 1001 with your ids
```

from: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/673

To find your uid and gid, see the first two number from here:

```
sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend to take a look at the new project RioFS (Userspace S3 filesystem): https://github.com/skoobe/riofs.

This project is “s3fs” alternative, the main advantages comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently [the project](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) is in the “testing” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

Regarding your issue, in order to run [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) as a root user and allow other users to have r/w access rights to the mounted directory:

1. make sure /etc/fuse.conf contains user_allow_other option
2. launch RioFS with -o "allow_other" parameter.

The whole command line to launch RioFS will look like:

```
sudo riofs -c /path/to/riofs.conf.xml http://s3.amazonaws.com mybucket.example.com /bucket
```

(make sure you exported both `AWSACCESSKEYID` and `AWSSECRETACCESSKEY` variables or set them in `riofs.conf.xml` configuration file).

Hope it helps you and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons, and I'm listing a possible reason as I encountered the same issue. If you look at your file permission, it could have inherited '---------' - no permissions/ACL.

If that's the case, you could add the "x-amz-meta-mode" to the meta data of the file. Do check out [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094543/mount-s3-s3fs-on-ec2-with-dynamic-files-persistent-public-permission-solved/18094544#18094544) on how to do it/do it dynamically.

Comment: this was my problem - I just `chmod 777`'ed it and got unstuck.

Comment: But how to add this header to files which are uploaded to storage by Amazon SES?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using centos you need to enable httpd_use_fusefs option otherwise no matter what you give for s3fs option it will never have the permission to access via httpd

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_fusefs on
```

Answer (score 0):

for all users to access the mounted bucket use the umask=0002 in the /etc/fstab file and remount the s3 bucket

example
fuse.s3fs _netdev,allow_other,umask=0002,passwd_file=/etc/passwdfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automount it from fstab the same **allow_other** needs to be added as mentioned above and the **user_allow_other** uncommented in /etc/fuse.conf
If you mount it from an AWS instance, I'd also recommend using instance-profile

```
s3fs#mys3bucketname /mnt/mys3folder fuse defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022,allow_other,_netdev,iam_role=my-instance-role-name 0 0
```

where *mys3bucketname* is your bucket in S3, *uid=1000 and gid=1000* are the user and group IDs for the user you want the S3 objects owned locally and *my-instance-role-name* is the instance-role attached to the instance-profile of the AWS instance you want to mount from, 0 0 is to disable ext3 dump and fsck