# How to mount AWS s3 using S3FS to allow full access to any user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have installed the latest s3fs on Centos 7 in AWS, and can mount my S3 bucket and read from it. My requirement is to allow any user to read, write, create and delete files and folders including other people's files and folders - basically a file and folder free-for-all.

In the fstab, I have this:

```
my-bucket /mnt/my-bucket fuse.s3fs _netdev,url=https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com,umask=0000,allow_other,rw,gid=0,uid=0 0 0
```

When I try to create a new folder called test as the centos user, I get the following error:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Operation not permitted

I have tried to chmod the mount point `/mnt` to 777 (the default was 755). I have also uncommented `# user_allow_other` in the `fuse.conf` file. Neither worked.

What are the correct umask, gid and uid (and other settings) in the fstab to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else seeing access denied type errors, the answer in this case was nothing to do with the command line - as confirmed above. The answer was that AWS KMS (CMK) encryption had been applied to the bucket but the S3FS user did not have read access to read the keys. Simply granting the AWS user read access to KMS keys via IAM policy fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Some of your options are unnecessary.  I successfully mounted a bucket with one user via:

```
s3fs bucket /path -f -o allow_other -o umask=000
```

And created a directory with a second user:

```
mkdir /path/dir
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works (albeit with fewer options). That is odd - I wonder why it is not working in my setup, therefore. I think I'll have to dig deeper and find out why my setup isn't working.